# Super class has attribute "b", still got "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'b' "

Tags: python, super

super class has instance attribute `b`, I am trying to access it using `super()` method, then why I am getting `Attribute Error`? It should access instance variable of superclass, but instead it is giving attribute error, anyone please tell where I am wrong.

Here superclass is defined `P`

Child class `C` inherits class `P`

```py
class P:
    a = 10
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 20

class C(P):
    a = 888
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 999
        super().__init__()
        print(super().a)
        print(super().b)

c = C()
```

Output

```bash
PS D:\python_practice> python .\test.py
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    c = C()
  File ".\test.py", line 19, in __init__
    print(super().b)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Answer (score 3):

`super()` is for finding attributes (usually methods, but as you can see, it works on class attributes as well) on a later *class* in the class method resolution order (MRO). Instance attributes aren't tied to a particular class in the hierarchy (they're all stored on the instance itself, typically in a single `dict` under the hood), you just look them up on `self` directly.

In this case, there is only one `b` attribute, and it's whatever was assigned last. Since you invoked `super().__init__()` after assigning to `self.b` in the child class, the parent class is replacing `self.b`, so `self.b = 999` is meaningless; instances of both parent and child will *only* have `self.b` with value `20` after initialization completes.

`super()` could be useful to find a *class* attribute on a superclass that has been shadowed by an *instance* attribute, but if both class and superclass used the same instance attribute name (and private name mangling is not involved) it's the *same* attribute shared by both, there is no distinction between the version used at different levels in the hierarchy.